# What is the best way to download an external file to a server via a program

Tags: php, wordpress, xss, auto-update

I have written a WordPress plugin, and I am trying to find the best way of having the program check for updates on my server, and downloading them automatically at the user's request.  This will basically be used to download extra features that I don't want to put into the WordPress repository due them not having the GNU license.

I've coded the program to check for updates, what I am not sure about is the download part.

Should I use file_get_contents() and then fwrite() to write the results to a directory?  I'm sure that's a way of doing it, but I am looking for the most cross-server safe way of doing this because the plugin is used by thousands of people on different setups, although they are all PHP, and most of them are PHP5+.  I am afraid certain hosts may have some sort of security preventing me from doing this.  Would cURL be a better option?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't re-invent the wheel! WordPress has an [HTTP API](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API) for this exact purpose!

Check out the codex for the essentials - http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API

You can also browse the source in `wp-includes/class-http.php`

Comment: You are correct, I found those functions shortly after posting this question.  WP has a number of functions available for downloading headers, files, extracting them, etc.  Unfortunately there isn't much documentation available on this apart from PHPDoc entries within the files.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`file_put_contents`](http://www.php.net/file_put_contents), which is much more efficient than loading everything into memory with `file_get_contents` and then calling `fwrite`. The second parameter accepts a stream resource, which you can open with [`fopen`](http://php.net/fopen) or (if you want to get around `allow_url_fopen` restrictions, [`fsockopen`](http://php.net/fsockopen)).

Therefore, the simplest option that uses only core functions (no curl extension, etc) and works in almost evry configuration is:

- Open a transport stream with [`fsockopen`](http://php.net/fsockopen)
- Send the HTTP headers manually with [`fwrite`](http://php.net/fwrite)
- Write the response with [`file_put_contents`](http://www.php.net/file_put_contents)

Comment: If your downloadable file is password protected somehow (basic HTTP auth, form-based login, etc...), then you'll have to use CURL. `file_get_contents()` is very basic and won't be able to handle any kind of authentication/login.

Comment: @Marc The http wrapper (which file_get_contents will use) can do basic authentication out of the box and you can implement digest authentication manually (granted, with some effort) if you need to. Form based logins can also be handled by the http wrapper since you can send arbitrary post data and arbitrary headers by creating the appropriate context. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php